# Animating Particle's Path with "Disappearing Tail" in Python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a 2d path, and I would like it to have a sort of "Disappearing Tail", where at any given time, it shows only the last 5 (for example) particles.

What I currently have is quite far from this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML

sample_path = np.random.uniform(size=(100,2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)        # x-array
line, = ax.plot(sample_path[0,0], sample_path[0,1])

def connect(i):
    (x0,y0) = sample_path[i-1,:]
    (x1,y1) = sample_path[i,:]
    plt.plot([x0,x1],[y0,y1],'ro-')
    return line,

def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, connect, np.arange(1, 100), init_func=init,
interval=200, blit=True)
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

This retains a 'full tail', i.e. after k steps, it shows all of the first k locations.

Is there a way to adapt what I've got so that the animation only shows the most recent history of the particle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably want to update the line instead of adding a lot of new points to the plot. Selecting the 5 most recent points can be done via indexing, e.g.

```
sample_path[i-5:i, 0]
```

Complete example, where we take care not to have a negative index and also don't use `blit` (which does not make sense if saving the animation).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc

r = np.sin(np.linspace(0,3.14,100))
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
sample_path = np.c_[r*(np.sin(t)+np.cos(t)), r*(np.cos(t)-np.sin(t))]/1.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line, = ax.plot(sample_path[0,0], sample_path[0,1], "ro-")

def connect(i):
    start=max((i-5,0))
    line.set_data(sample_path[start:i,0],sample_path[start:i,1])
    return line,

ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, connect, np.arange(1, 100), interval=200)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A small variation on this problem - how hard is it to adapt this example to showing two paths (again, with disappearing tails), each in different colours (say, one red and the other blue)?

Comment: Not hard at all.

Comment: Ah - just played around with it a bit and got it to work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not as good as ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer technically, but it still does the job and looks pretty cool, just plot the latest points and clear the old ones. I added a few more and sped it up because I thought it looked better with a longer trail.

```
def connect(i):
    #clear current points
    plt.clf()

    #prevent axis auto-resizing
    plt.plot(0,0)
    plt.plot(1,1)

    #generate points to plot
    (x0,y0) = sample_path[i-8,:]
    (x1,y1) = sample_path[i-7,:]
    (x2,y2) = sample_path[i-6,:]
    (x3,y3) = sample_path[i-5,:]
    (x4,y4) = sample_path[i-4,:]
    (x5,y5) = sample_path[i-3,:]
    (x6,y6) = sample_path[i-2,:]
    (x7,y7) = sample_path[i-1,:]
    (x8,y8) = sample_path[i,:]

    #plot old points
    plt.plot([x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7],[y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7],'ro-')

    #plot new point in blue
    plt.plot([x7,x8],[y7,y8],'bo-')
    return line,

def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, connect, frames=np.arange(1, 100), 
init_func=init,
interval=50, blit=True)
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this! I'll play around with this a bit as well - I like that it distinguishes the newest point being placed, which might be useful for my purposes.